# ARM assembly working out x^n using recursion and stacks

Tags: recursion, assembly, arm, stack

I have an assignment that asks me to work out x^n using recursion. The C source code for the function power is provide, and I have to translate it to assembly language, however I am new to assembly and a bit stuck, so not sure what to do.

Here is my code so far:

```
        AREA powerXn, CODE, READONLY
        ENTRY

        MOV r0, #2                      ;Value of x.
        MOV r1, #3                      ;Value of n.
        ADR sp, stack                   ;Points sp to start of stack.
        BL main
loop    B loop

main    STMFD sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, lr} ;Pushes registers on to stack.
        BL power
        LDMFD sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, pc} ;Pops values from stack.

power   STMFD sp!, {r0, r1, lr}         ;Pushes registers on to stack.
        CMP r1, #0                      ;Checks the base case
        MOVEQ r2, #1                    ;Sets r2 to be 1 if base case is reached
        BNE test                        ;If base case not reached, jump to test.

        MUL r3, r0, r2              
        LDMFD sp!, {r0, r1, pc}

test    TST r1, #1                      ;Checks if r1 (n) is odd
        BNE odd                         ;If it is odd, jump to odd
        BEQ even                        ;Otherwise jump to even

odd     SUB r1, r1, #1                  ;Subtract 1 from r1 (n).
        BL power                        ;Recurse back to power.
        MUL r3, r0, r2              
        LDMFD sp!, {r0, r1, pc}

even    ;Not sure what to do here and not sure if what i have done so far is right.


        AREA powerXn, DATA, READWRITE
        ALIGN
        space 0x200
stack   DCD 0x00
        END
```

this C source code that i need to translate is:

```
int power(int x, unsigned int n){
 int y;

 if (n == 0)
      return 1;

 if (n & 1) // if n is odd
      return x * power(x, n - 1);
 else { // if n is even  
      y = power(x, n >> 1); // n >> 1 means n/2
      return y * y;
 }
}
```

Comment: It's wrong. Also, it has instructions without comments. Hard to tell what you wanted to do with `MUL r3, r0, r2` when that should be the `return 1` case for example. Furthermore the return value is typically in `r0` so saving/restoring that overwrites the result even if you calculated it correctly.

Comment: How will your code be checked for correctness? Can you actually compile and run it? Any limit imposed on n? (as overflow is an issue here).

Comment: I misread the question as asking for this *without* recursion / stacks.  (Recursion is fine for theoretical discussions of algorithms, or languages with smart compilers, but a poor implementation strategy in asm).  This algorithm can be transformed to iterative by moving the multiply inside the arg-setup for `power` to make it tail-recursive, then transform to a loop and simplify. See Alexander Stepanov's Spoils of the Egyptians: Lecture 2 Part 1: https://youtu.be/PtGVOGui7q4?t=428&index=3&list=PLHxtyCq_WDLV5N5zUCBCDC2WqF1VBDGg1 (includes playlist for the lecture series)

Comment: https://youtu.be/etZgaSjzqlU?t=37m6s in the 2nd part of that lecture is where Stepanov generalizes from `+` to `*`, making a power function instead of multiply from the same right-shift and do something special on set bits in `n` algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be more familiar with C, so I suggest going to https://godbolt.org/ and trying their C-to-assembler feature. All you have to do is to choose a correct compiler (there are options for ARM GCC) and look through the assembler code. Of course, I strongly disagree with simple copying of the code without trying to understand it first, but that website should give you at least a clue on what to do. I am currently learning x86 assembler with FASM and this website is the go-to place for me during research.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for the link! It looks very helpful, so will look in to it.